# In Pandas, how can I include the date column that I am grouping by in the list of columns on the dataframe?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, data-science

I have a dataframe that starts out something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['orders'] = orders_df.groupby(['d'])['order_id'].count()
print(df.columns)
```

When I do the above, the "d" column is missing from the output of `df.columns` -- why is this?

Secondarily, I'm unable to `df.rename({'d':'date'})`

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Add reset_index.   `df = df.reset_index()`  then `print(df.columns)`  after your assignment to orders.

Answer (score 0):

You could [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `as_index=False`:

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd

orders_df = pd.DataFrame({'order_id' : [1, 2, 3, 4], 'd' : [2, 2, 3, 3]})
```

**Code**

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df[['d', 'orders']] = orders_df.groupby(['d'], as_index=False)['order_id'].count()

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   d  orders
0  2       2
1  3       2
```

Finally you need to use [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) with `axis=1`:

```
print(df.rename({'d': 'date'}, axis=1))
```

**Output**

```
   date  orders
0     2       2
1     3       2
```

Answer (score 0):

First your output is `series` and columns `d` is a `index`

```
orders_df.groupby(['d'])['order_id'].count()
```

Fix it

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['orders'] = orders_df.groupby(['d'])['order_id'].count()
df=df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'d'})
```